# Exact Particle Filtering Derivation

Tags: bayesian, hidden-markov-model, particle-filter

I am very confused with one of the derivations used by this paper http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.409.2389&rep=rep1&type=pdf in pg 1021 of this paper. It is a simple use of the applications of bayes theorem. Note $y^t=y_{1:t} $ and $x^t=x_{1:t}$. It uses this fact that $p(y_{t+1},x_{t+1}|x_t)=p(x_{t+1}|y_{t+1},x_t)p(y_{t+1}|x_t)$

$$p(x_{t+1}|y^{t+1}) \propto \int p(y_{t+1}|x_t)p(x_{t+1}|x_t, y_{t+1})p(x_t|y^t) dx_t$$

I am guessing that this uses a lot of hidden Markov assumptions to simplify the expression of the densities i.e. $x_{t+1}$ is only dependent on $x_{t}$ and $y_{t}$ is only dependent on $x_{t}$, but it does not seem to fall out in my case. What I tried is?

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
p(x_{t+1}|y^{t+1}) & \propto \int p(x_{t+1},x_t|y^{t+1}) dx_t \\
& \propto \int p(x_{t+1}|x_t,y^{y+1})p(x_t|y^{t+1}) dx_t ~~(by~conditional)\\
& \propto \int p(y_{t+1}|x_{t+1},x_{t},y^{t})p(x_{t+1}|x_t,y^t)p(x_t|y^{t+1})dx_t~~(by~bayes)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

The last line can possibly simplify to $\propto \int p(y_{t+1}|x_{t+1})p(x_{t+1}|x_t)p(x_t|y^{t+1})dx_t$ by conditional dependence of hidden Markov model as I understand it, but as you can see the answer is different.So my question is **What have I done wrong in the last step?** Notice I did not make use of the fact they gave me.

Answer (score 1):

I dislike the notation $y^{t+1}$ because it can easily be confused with an exponent. Thus, I  will use $y_{1:t+1}$. I also think in this case, this notation may have confused you.

$$ 
\begin{array}{rll}
p(x_{t+1}|y_{1:t+1}) &
= \int p(x_{t+1},x_t|y_{1:t+1}) dx_t  \\
&\propto \int p(y_{t+1},x_{t+1}|x_t,y_{1:t})p(x_t|y_{1:t}) dx_t & \mbox{(by Bayes)} \\
&= \int p(y_{t+1},x_{t+1}|x_t)p(x_t|y_{1:t}) dx_t & \mbox{(cond. ind.)} \\
&= \int p(y_{t+1}|x_t)p(x_{t+1}|y_{t+1},x_t)p(x_t|y_{1:t}) dx_t & \mbox{(by fact provided)} \\
\end{array} $$

But I'm not sure how this is helpful since you generally don't know $p(y_{t+1}|x_t)$ or $p(x_{t+1}|y_{t+1},x_t)$. Typically the following derivation is more helpful.

$$ 
\begin{array}{rll}
p(x_{t+1}|y_{1:t+1}) &
= \int p(x_{t+1},x_t|y_{1:t+1}) dx_t &  \\
&\propto \int p(y_{t+1}|x_{t+1},x_t,y_{1:t})p(x_{t+1},x_t|y_{1:t}) dx_t & \mbox{(by Bayes)} \\
&= \int p(y_{t+1}|x_{t+1})p(x_{t+1},x_t|y_{1:t}) dx_t & \mbox{(cond. ind.)} \\
&= \int p(y_{t+1}|x_{t+1})p(x_{t+1}|x_t,y_{1:t})p(x_t|y_{1:t}) dx_t  \\
&= \int p(y_{t+1}|x_{t+1})p(x_{t+1}|x_t)p(x_t|y_{1:t}) dx_t & \mbox{(cond. ind.)}
\end{array} $$

Because $p(y_{t+1}|x_{t+1})$ and $p(x_{t+1}|x_t)$ are the observation and evolution equation respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It appears that the line with the words (by fact provided) has been plugged in wrongly. Can you please let me know whether you meant that line to be $\int p(x_{t+1}|y_{t+1},x_t)p(y_{t+1}|x_t)p(x_t|y_{1:t})$. If so, then you have solved it. And so with the following sentence, you mean to say that $p(y_{t+1}|x_t)$ and $p(x_{t+1}|y_{t+1},x_{t})$ are not generally known. I do agree with your opinion on the notation. It can often be confused with the index of the particles as well.

Comment: Yes, there was a typo. The $x_{t+1}$ is now removed in the appropriate place from both of those lines.